# Create Modern OpenGL context using WGL?

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, wgl

I'm trying to create an OpenGL context (Modern Version) using Windows functions.

***Basically the code is just:***

1. Create window class
2. Register the class
3. create a Window
4. choose `PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR` & set it
5. Create a legacy OpenGL context
6. Make context current
7. `glewInit()`
8. Create new window
9. Create a modern pixel format attrib array
10. Set the format
11. Create modern OpenGL context
12. Make context current

After this I try to draw a square (using a VAO & VBO).

The result is: the *Windows* window works, the `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` works, but the square is not drawn (`display()` function).

If I use an OpenGL 2.0 context, it draws the square (using a VAO & VBO as before), so the problem must be on the init of OpenGL 3.2.

Where am I going wrong?

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/wglew.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool progRun = false;

void display(){
   glUseProgram(shaderProg);
   glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);
   glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0,4);
}

string errorStr = "none";

PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;

HGLRC hrc; // vars to init glew
HDC hdc;
HWND hwnd;

HGLRC hrc1; //vars for the real window
HDC hdc1;
HWND hwnd1;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM ); // window event hadler prototype

//-------------------- INIT OPENGL
int initOpengl(
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
    int       nCmdShow
)
{
    //---- fake Window
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof( WNDCLASSEX );
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon( NULL, IDI_APPLICATION );
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor( NULL, IDC_ARROW );
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)( COLOR_WINDOW + 1 );
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = "coco";
    wcex.hIconSm = NULL;

    if( !RegisterClassEx( &wcex ) )
    {
        errorStr = "RegisterClassEx";
        return 0;
    }
    hwnd = CreateWindow(
        "coco",
        "dddd",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        500, 500,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );

    hdc = GetDC( hwnd );

    memset( &pfd, 0, sizeof( PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR ) );
    pfd.nSize = sizeof( PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR );
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 32;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 32;
    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

    int nPixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat( hdc, &pfd );

    SetPixelFormat( hdc, nPixelFormat, &pfd );

    hrc = wglCreateContext( hdc );

    wglMakeCurrent( hdc, hrc );

    glewExperimental = true;
    glewInit();

    //---------------For the real window
    if( wglewIsSupported( "WGL_ARB_create_context" ) == 1 )
    {
        wglMakeCurrent( NULL, NULL );
        wglDeleteContext( hrc );
        ReleaseDC( hwnd, hdc );
        DestroyWindow( hwnd );

        hwnd1 = CreateWindow(
            "coco",
            "ddddd",
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
            CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
            500, 500,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            hInstance,
            NULL
        );

        hdc1 = GetDC( hwnd1 );

        const int iPixelFormatAttribList[] = {
            WGL_DRAW_TO_WINDOW_ARB, GL_TRUE,
            WGL_SUPPORT_OPENGL_ARB, GL_TRUE,
            WGL_DOUBLE_BUFFER_ARB, GL_TRUE,
            WGL_PIXEL_TYPE_ARB, WGL_TYPE_RGBA_ARB,
            WGL_COLOR_BITS_ARB, 32,
            WGL_DEPTH_BITS_ARB, 24,
            WGL_STENCIL_BITS_ARB, 8,
            0 // End of attributes list
        };
        int attributes[] = {
            WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3
            , WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 2
            , WGL_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB, WGL_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB
            , 0
        };

        int nPixelFormat = 0;
        UINT iNumFormats = 0;

        wglChoosePixelFormatARB( hdc1, iPixelFormatAttribList, NULL, 1, &nPixelFormat, (UINT*)&iNumFormats );

        SetPixelFormat( hdc1, nPixelFormat, &pfd );

        hrc1 = wglCreateContextAttribsARB( hdc1, 0, attributes );

        wglMakeCurrent( NULL, NULL );
        wglMakeCurrent( hdc1, hrc1 );
    }
    else
    {
        errorStr = "WGL_ARB_create_context";
        return 0;
    }
    return true;
}


// MAIN -----

int CALLBACK WinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
    int       nCmdShow
)
{
    initOpengl( hInstance, hPrevInstance, lpCmdLine, nCmdShow );

    ShowWindow( hwnd1, SW_SHOW );

    glClearColor( 1, 0, 0, 1 );

    MSG msg;
    progRun = true;

    while( progRun )
    {
        if( PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ) )
        {
            TranslateMessage( &msg );
            DispatchMessage( &msg );
        }

        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
        glViewport( 0, 0, 500, 500 );
        display();

        SwapBuffers( hdc1 );
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    return DefWindowProc( hWnd, message, wParam, lParam );
}
```

Comment: If you want OpenGL 3.2 don't ask for 3.1. Also, I recomend setting a Core Profile flag for context attributes (no old fixed-pipeline commands). Also, GL_QUADS is not valid in Core Profile. Also, do your rendering (display + swapbuffers) in the WM_PAINT handler. If you dont use `glViewPort` then your rendering does not fit the window when it changes its size. Also, set a `glClearColor` for your background, better not black, so as to tell if GL is working or not.

Comment: I advise to separate OS functions from GL stuff. Write special functions for window creation, size-change, paint, context creation, shaders, data, camera, rendering, user actions, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in the context creation code alone, but in the combination of the used OpenGL version and the drawing code.

When requesting an OpenGL context as it is done in the question, there are several attributes that can be set. The relevant one here is the `WGL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB` (which is not set). The [extension description](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/WGL_ARB_create_context.txt) states:

> The default value for WGL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB is     WGL_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB. [...] If the requested OpenGL version is less than 3.2,
>       WGL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB is ignored and the functionality of the
>       context is determined solely by the requested version.

This means that the code in the question requests a OpenGL 3.2 Core Profile in the not working version a 3.1 (compatibility) profile in the other case.

In a core profile, the use of `GL_QUADS` as mode for `glDrawArrays` is deprecated and cannot be used. Due to this, the quad isn't rendered. Note, that you would have found the problem ways faster if you would check for OpenGL errors (`glGetError`) in your code since it would have reported a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` for the draw command.

There are two ways how the problem can be solved:

- Stop drawing quads and draw triangles instead (`GL_TRIANGLES`). This is the recommended way.
- Explicitly request a OpenGL 3.2 compatibility profile by adding a  `WGL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB` with the value `WGL_CONTEXT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE_BIT_ARB`. But note, that this might cause problems in the future because mixing old OpenGL code with modern OpenGL can lead to problems.

Comment: ya it work, that was the problem.. uuff finally THANKS A LOT